# Count number of objects in JSON PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON array and in that I have 3 JSON objects. I want to count the number of objects that is 3. but it is giving me 1. If I do not add the key "`like`", then it works. but after adding it, it is not working.

```
 $JSON = '{"like":['
            . '{"username":"suraj","password":"abc"},'
            . '{"username":"don","password":"abc"},'
            . '{"username":"rana","password":"abc"}'
            . ']}';


    $jsonInPHP = json_decode($JSON);
    echo count($jsonInPHP);
```

Comment: `count($jsonInPHP['like'])` or `count($jsonInPHP->like)`

Comment: $jsonInPHP = json_decode($JSON,true);
    echo count($jsonInPHP['like']);

Comment: Note: If you set the 2nd param as `true` it makes it an associative array.

Comment: thanks ... $jsonInPHP->like did this for me

Comment: what if I want to count all the usernames only ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON represents an object, not an array. In your object, you have `like` property which is an array so you need to write like this

```
count($jsonInPHP->like);
```

Answer (score 4):

pass the second parameter `true` like this

```
 $jsonInPHP = json_decode($JSON,true); 
  echo count($jsonInPHP['like']);
```

Comment: adding true gives error,, though i got solution,, count($jsonInPHP->like);

Answer (score 1):

This happens because after json decoding your string you get object with one property (`like`) (or array with one element with key `like`).

In both ways you want to count size of this property (or key) which is:

```
// if $jsonInPHP is array
echo count($jsonInPHP['like']); 
// if $jsonInPHP is object
echo count($jsonInPHP->like);
```